# Write multiple NumPy arrays into CSV file in separate columns?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

How to write multiple numpy arrays into one csv file in multiple columns？

```
import numpy
import csv

arrA = numpy.array(file.root.a)
arrB = numpy.array(file.root.b)
arrC = numpy.array(file.root.c)

for i in range (480):
    for j in range (640):
        (write arrA[i,j] into column1,write arrB[i,j] into column2,write arrC[i,j] into column3)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
output = np.column_stack((arrA.flatten(),arrB.flatten(),arrC.flatten()))
np.savetxt('output.dat',output,delimiter=',')
```

Comment: I got:File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/io.py", line 542, in savetxt
    fh.write(format % tuple(row) + '\n')
TypeError: float argument required

Comment: What are the sizes and data types of `arrA`, `arrB`, and `arrC`?

Comment: What are the *shapes* of the arrays; i.e. what is `arrA.shape`?

Comment: @oops: updated my answer. `np.dstack` was adding an extra dimension to `updated`.